# Error build darknet windows 10 cuda and cudnn 11.2

Tags: visual-studio-code, darknet, yolov4

I want to build darknet for YOLOv4. my configuration is: win10, microsoft visual studio code 2019, openCV 4.5.1, cuda and cudnn 11.2.
I followed some tutorial that I need to edit "yolo_cpp_dll.vcxproj" and "darknet.vcxproj" in "\ darknet \ build \ darknet" from cuda 10.1 to the cuda version I am using (11.2)
when i try to build "yolo_cpp_dll.vcxproj" with visual studio code i get this 11 error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MSB3721 The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
> Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin\nvcc.exe"
> -gencode=arch=compute_30,code="sm_30,compute_30" -gencode=arch=compute_75,code="sm_75,compute_75" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu
> -I\include -IC:\opencv_3.0\opencv\build\include -I....\include -I....\3rdparty\stb\include -I....\3rdparty\pthreads\include -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include" -I\include -I\include -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release
> -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static    -DCUDNN_HALF -DCUDNN -DGPU -DLIB_EXPORTS -D_TIMESPEC_DEFINED -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_LIB -D_WINDLL -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Fdx64\DLL_Release\vc142.pdb /FS   /MD " -o
> x64\DLL_Release\activation_kernels.cu.obj
> "C:\Users\user\Documents\Pen1\darknet\src\activation_kernels.cu""
> exited with code 1.   yolo_cpp_dll    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
> 11.2.targets  785

please help, how to solve this?
or anyone knows how to build darknet with my configuration?

Comment: MSB3721/exited with code 1 is not sufficient to find out what the actual issue is.  You'll need to increase the VS verbosity to find the actual error reported by `nvcc`.  How to do this is covered in [many places on the web](http://yuchaozh.github.io/2019/03/08/Change-Build-Verbosity-In-Visual-Studio/).  It's also good practice to [verify a CUDA install](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#verify-installation) before attempting to use it to build other things.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have verified cuda installation, it passed. and my VS verbosity is detailed. i copy that error message from error tab in vs. thank you for responding to my question

Comment: i try to solve this problem. 
i changed compute_30,sm_30 to compute_50,sm_ in yolo_cpp_dll.vcxproj and darknet.vcxproj